# update attack bit board when one attack is updated

Tags: python, bitboard

This is just a principle. I would like the attacked bitboard to be updated when one of the attacks bitboards (knight, bishop or pawn) is altered without having to repeat line 1. Is this possible? what is the best way to do this? In borg class way or simply using the behaviour of dictionaries:

1. attacked = pawn_attacks | knight_attacks | bishop_attacks
2. pawn_attacks = (1 << (pawn + 9)) | (1<< (pawn + 7))

This doesn't work transparently / automatically when one of the attacks changes. Below the result of attacked is always 1.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pawn_attacks = 0
        self.knight_attacks = 0
        self.bishop_attacks = 0

    @property
    def attacked(self):
        return self.pawn_attacks | self.knight_attacks | self.bishop_attacks

test = Test()
test.pawn_attacks = 1
print test.attacked
test.pawn_attacks = 2
print test.attacked
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing a class, you can make `attacked` a (read-only) property so it gets transparently recomputed at need:

```
... rest of the class ...

@property
def attacked(self):
    return self.pawn_attacks | self.knight_attacks | self.bishop_attacks
```

Now given an instance `x` of the class, `x.attacked` will always be up to date (caching to only recompute if needed is not warranted, given that the operation is so elementary anyway).

If you're not willing to make a class you'll have to make `attacked` specifically a *function* to get the same idea working.  However while Python doesn't force you to use classes the way some other languages do, nevertheless using classes when they provide structure and/or convenience, like here, is still a good idea:-)

Comment: You're assigning `test.pawn_attacked = 2` and that **`pawn_attacked`** (as opposed to the **`pawn_attacks`** assigned previously & used and assigned everywhere) attribute is never used or referenced again anywhere in your code; what did you **expect** to happen as a result of such an attribute assignment, to an attribute unrelated to anything else mentioned in either the question or the answer?!  I suspect it's a typo, in which case the obvious question becomes, how does **your** typo invalidate **my** answer, pray?

Comment: Yes, definitively a typo :)